# Show that $x^n + ax + p$ is irreducible, $p$ prime, $a \in \mathbb Z, \lvert a \rvert < p - 1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Show that the polynomial $x^n + ax + p$ is irreducible, $p$ prime, $a \in \mathbb Z, \lvert a \rvert < p - 1$.
I tried reduction, Eisenstein and linear transformation (plugging in $x+1$, $x+p$) but nothing did work. Any solutions?

Comment: Please show your workings of your attempts; perhaps you made an error in using them, which we can help you discover.  I.e., don't claim you've done anything unless you're willing to post what you claim to have done, along with the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $x^n+ax+p = fg$ were reducible, with nonconstant monic $f,g\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$. Since $p$ is prime, we can assume the constant term of $f$ be $\pm 1$. So products of roots of $f$ has absolute value $1$, one of the root $r$ must satisfy $|r|\leq1$.

However, $|r^n + ar| \leq 1+|a| < p$, contradicting to the fact that $r^n+ar+p=0$.